# TLS 1.1 with Oracle HTTP Server?

Tags: oracle, ssl, tls

Is there a way to enable TLS 1.1 on Oracle HTTP Server (which I believe is a custom version of Apache)?  Right now I'm getting a SSLv3 response and need to use TLS 1.1

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to do that? There's very limited browser support for TLS1.1. Wikipedia has the following list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Browser_implementations

- Apple's Safari supports TLS, but it’s not officially specified which version.[22] On Operating Systems(Safari uses the TLS implementation of the underlying Operating System) like Mac OS X 10.5.8, Mac OS X 10.6.6, Windows XP, Windows Vista or Windows 7, Safari 5 has been reported to support TLS 1.0.[23]
- Mozilla Firefox, versions 2 and above, support TLS 1.0.[24] As of December 2010, Firefox does not support TLS 1.1 or 1.2.[25]
- Microsoft Internet Explorer always uses the TLS implementation of the underlying Microsoft Windows Operating System, a service called SChannel Security Service Provider. Internet Explorer 8 in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 supports TLS 1.2. Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008R2 use the same code (Microsoft Windows Version 6.1 (build 7600)) similar to how Windows Vista sp1 uses the same code as Windows 2008 Server.[26]
- As of Presto 2.2, featured in Opera 10, Opera supports TLS 1.2.[27]

Unless you really tightly control both ends you should re-examine the requirements for TLS1.1.